# Как сделать проверку на то что пользователь существует в nextjs при использование middleware?

Tags: nextjs, next.js, middleware

Для аутентификации использую next-auth@5.0.0-beta.5, вот такая конструкция,

middleware.js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "@/app/authConfig";

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)'],
}
```

authConfig.js

```
export const authConfig = {
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
            console.log('authorized');
            const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
            const isOnLogin = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login');
            const callbackUrl = nextUrl.searchParams.get('callbackUrl') || '/dashboard';

            if (!isLoggedIn) {
                return false;
            } else if (isLoggedIn && isOnLogin) {
                return Response.redirect(new URL(decodeURIComponent(callbackUrl), nextUrl));
            }

            return true;
        },
    },
    providers: [],
};
```

auth.js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { authConfig } from "./authConfig";
import { login } from "./lib/actions";

export const {
    signIn,
    signOut,
    auth
} = NextAuth({
    ...authConfig,
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                try {
                    const user = await login(credentials);
                    return user;
                } catch (error) {
                    throw error;
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                const roleLevel = ['user', 'worker', 'admin'];

                token.username = user.username;
                token.fullname = user.fullname;
                token.role = user.role;
                token.roleLevel = roleLevel.indexOf(user.role);
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (token) {
                session.user.username = token.username;
                session.user.fullname = token.fullname;
                session.user.role = token.role;
                session.user.roleLevel = token.roleLevel;
            }
            return session;
        },
    },
});
```

Так вот логин, и все другие функции работают хорошо, но вот есть проблемка, если например пользователь с ролью админ, был удален, и он еще находится в систему, то он может без проблем создать новую запись, так вот я хочу сделать проверку на то существует ли пользователь, что если бы он был удален, то при любом взаимодействие с системой его выкидывало на логин. Но не могу понять как правильно это реализовать,
К примеру вот функция addNewUser

```
export const addNewUser = async (formData) => {
    try {
        const { username, fullname, password, role } = Object.fromEntries(formData);

        const session = await auth();
        if (session.user.role !== 'admin') {
            return { isSuccess: false, status: 'error', message: 'you don`t have access!' };
        }

        if (!username || !fullname || !password || !role) {
            return { isSuccess: false, status: 'error', message: 'One of the fields is empty!' };
        }

        const connection = await ConnectToDB();
        const usernameQuery = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE BINARY username = ?';
        const [isUserExist] = await connection.execute(usernameQuery, [username]);

        if (isUserExist.length > 0) {
            return { isSuccess: false, status: 'error', message: 'The username is already taken!' };
        }

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        const addQuery = 'INSERT INTO users (username, fullname, password, role) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
        const [user] = await connection.execute(addQuery, [username, fullname, hashedPassword, role]);

        if (user.affectedRows === 0) {
            return { isSuccess: false, status: 'error', message: 'There was an error when adding it!' };
        } else {
            revalidatePath('/users');
            return { isSuccess: true, status: 'success', message: 'A user has been added!', data: user[0] };
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        return { isSuccess: false, status: 'error', message: e.sqlMessage ?? (e.message ?? e) };
    }
}
```

тут много проверок, и одна из них что пользователь является админом через const session = await auth();

Сразу отвечу на то что можно же добавить

```
const usernameQuery = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE BINARY username = ?';
const [isUserExist] = await connection.execute(usernameQuery, [session.username]);

if (isUserExist.length === 0) {
   // Ошибка что пользователя нету, и перенаправить на логин.
}
```

Да такой способ сработает, но когда запросов много, нужно в каждый добавить такую проверку, это очень много, и хотелось бы один раз написать в middleware который при каждом взаимодействие сам проверит, и выдаст ошибку если нет пользователя.

Еще в middleware authorized у меня почему-то пустой auth?.user = {} и я не могу вытащить из него имя пользователя чтобы проверить его. А если пытаюсь получить сессию или что-то подобное типа

```
import { getSession } from "./lib/actions";
```

получаю ошибку Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

Поэтому прошу совета, как правильно реализовать проверку существует ли пользователь.